# Sphinx Search Error. Not indexing

Tags: php, macos, indexing, sphinx

This is my conf file :

```
source src1
{

type = mysql
sql_host = localhost
sql_user = root
sql_pass = rootpass
sql_db = something
sql_port = 9306

sql_query = \
    SELECT id, username, firstname, lastname , gender , email , created_on FROM user

sql_attr_timestamp = created_on
}

index users
{

source = src1
charset_type = sbcs

}
```

But when I try to index it using Indexer, this is the output that I end up getting without anything indexed :

```
indexer --config /var/www/mysite/sphinx.conf --all
Sphinx 2.0.9-release (rel20-r4115)
Copyright (c) 2001-2013, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2013, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/var/www/mysite/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'users'...
ERROR: index 'users': key 'path' not found.
total 0 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 0 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERROR: index 'users': key 'path' not found.

Your index has no `path` - you need to tell sphinx where to save the index!